# Doctrine: calculating datetime difference

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, datediff

How can i calculate the difference between datetime column and now (for example 'created_at' and NOW()) in Doctrine?

I Googled it alot and couldn't find an answer..

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
$query->select('DATEDIFF(NOW(), datetime column)')
```

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work, and when i run the query `SELECT DATEDIFF(NOW(), \`created_at\`) FROM \`user\` WHERE \`id\` = 14` in my DB i get `0`, but when i `SELECT NOW(), \`created_at\`` i get the dates correctly.. could it have something to do with the column type being DATETIME instead of something else?

Comment: Strange thing that TIMEDIFF works and DATEDIFF doesn't. Maybe the result is less than a day..

Answer (score 0):

try
$query -> select(DATE_DIFF(CURRENT_DATE(), datetime column))

DQL dont use now() sql function, they use CURRENT_DATE() instead

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).